# How to change user password in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Something strange happened and I am lost how to fix it.

I own a mail service of which I change the admin password every 6 months. 2 days ago I changed it like always, so i wanted to login again and it didn't accepted my new password. Very weird. But it also won't accept my old password. I have never had an issue like this.

So I locked myself out and the only way to get me in again is trying to change the password in the database itself with phpmyadmin.

So I installed phpmyadmin and logged into the database where I can see my admin accounts.

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/NjhX8Wp5/Screenshot-2021-06-27-at-21-14-43.png]

I tried to change the password in the password area with a normal text string, but it won't accept it. So, to be honest I am kinda lost right now what to do.

How can I reset the password for my admin account in the database, so I can login again?

Comment: Without the ability to create a new account, you won’t be able, to replace the password hash (and the salt) with a password you know.  You have no choice but to reinstall the Mail service in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a summary of the article
[How to Reset Your Admin Password in phpMyAdmin](https://support.pinnaclecart.com/support/solutions/articles/44000588062-how-to-reset-your-admin-password-in-phpmyadmin):

- Open phpMyAdmin and click the `admins` table on the left
- Find your user in the username column and click "Edit" on the
  left side of the row
- In the password row

  - Highlight the current password hash and delete
  - Enter the new password in that field and set the drop-down menu on
    the left of it to SHA1 or MD5, as required
- If the account is locked, change the active row drop-down menu from
  *Block* to *Yes*
- Scroll to the bottom and click the Go button.

You should now be able to login with the new password.

See the linked article for more details and screenshots for every step.

Comment: Thank you, after selecting MD5 and a new password it worked. Thank you very much!!

Comment: On ubuntu/debian systems exists a maintain user which can be used as a second root user to get access again

Comment: What about the salt?

Comment: To have the best success use a simple password with no special characters (abc123) AND if there are TWO "GO" buttons, make sure you push the LAST one. Harrymc's instructions didn't work until I did these extra steps.  _Once you get access, IMMEDIATELY change the user password to something stronger_

Answer (score 0):

Very good answer by harrymc. Only thing I have to add is sometimes the original user role for admin may not work especially for php applications like lavarel or codeignitor possibly because of sessions, cookies, etc which would even be stored in the same users table.

So solution I would recommend that worked for me was.
If your application has a registration page, then you are in luck!

1. Just register a new user in you application and ensure you can login with that user.
2. Go to phpmyadmin and change user role to 1. (Ensure its the same user role of the current Admin)

Found this solution better for me because encrypting new changed password with  md5 of sha1 was not making any difference to the existing Admin, I could not logon, but now I can.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160188)